# A simple vault saving IERC20, but fails a simple foundry test

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm, foundry-rs

I wrote a simple vault for a particular IERC20 contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract BasicVault {
    mapping (address => uint) user_to_balance_;
    IERC20 immutable token_;

    event Deposit(address indexed user, uint amount);
    event Withdraw(address indexed user, uint amount);

    constructor(address addr) {
        token_ = IERC20(addr);
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) external {
        user_to_balance_[msg.sender] += amount;
        // Note: in the front end, user has to call IERC20::allowance() to allow the amount
        // to be transfered.
        require(token_.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount));
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) external {
        // Note: It is suggested to change the state before calling into another contract.
        // The external contract overrides the control flow in the middle which can be dangerous.
        // E.g. if the current contract will send the money based on the user_to_balance,
        // and we don't modify the user_to_balance before the send behavior. When the send is triggered
        // in the attacker's context, the attacker can call withdraw again -- which will continuously
        // withdraw the money from BasicVault to the attacker without modifying the user_to_balance.
        user_to_balance_[msg.sender] -= amount;
        require(token_.transfer(msg.sender, amount));
        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

One test code using foundry is also listed here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "../src/BasicVault.sol";

contract BasicVaultTest is Test {
    BasicVault public counter;
    IERC20 public WETH;

    function setUp() public {

        WETH = IERC20(vm.envAddress("WETH"));
        assertEq(address(WETH), address(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2));
        counter = new BasicVault(address(WETH));

        string memory rpc = vm.envString("ETH_RPC_URL");
        uint forkId = vm.createFork(rpc);
        vm.selectFork(forkId);

        vm.label(address(counter), "Vault");
        vm.label(address(this), "Caller");
        vm.label(address(WETH), "WETH");
    }

    function testDepositWithdraw(uint amount) public {
        if (amount == 0) return;
        // address(this) will allow amount of WETH to be spent by address(counter).
        WETH.approve(address(counter), amount);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(counter)), 0);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(this)), 0);
        assertEq(WETH.allowance(address(this), address(counter)), amount);

        // Note: the way to transform an address to a payable.
        (bool sent, ) = payable(address(WETH)).call{value: amount}("");
        // Note: send()/transfer() will not work here because the gas limit
        // for those two function is only 2300 to prevent potential attack.
        // Here WETH has a fallback function does more things.
        // payable(address(WETH)).send/transfer(amount);
        assert(sent);

        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(counter)), 0);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(this)), amount);
        assertEq(WETH.allowance(address(this), address(counter)), amount);
        counter.deposit(amount);
        assertEq(WETH.allowance(address(this), address(counter)), 0);

        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(counter)), amount);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(this)), 0);
        assertEq(WETH.allowance(address(this), address(counter)), 0);
        counter.withdraw(amount - 1);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(counter)), 1);
        assertEq(WETH.balanceOf(address(this)), amount - 1);
        assertEq(WETH.allowance(address(this), address(counter)), 0);

        // withdraw morn than deposit
        vm.expectRevert();
        counter.withdraw(2);
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out that **counter.deposit(amount);** got reverted in the transformFrom for some reason. I have read the [WETH9 code](https://github.com/gnosis/canonical-weth/blob/master/contracts/WETH9.sol), seems pretty straightforward. Could anyone help to figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: did you make sure you called approve, on the contract which is spending your tokens prior to the deposit call.